# Undecidable statements of second-order arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic

What are examples of statements of second order arithmetic (SOA) that  are undecided by that theory? How do they relate  to the existence of large cardinals?

Comment: For example, you can ask whether there exists a real coding a model of ZFC.

Comment: What kind of second-order arithmetic? Arithmetic with full second-order semantics is categorical and therefore complete. Axiomatic second-order arithmetic such as $Z_2$ is, despite the name, an ordinary *first-order* theory in a two-sorted language, so you can take e.g. $\mathrm{Con}_{Z_2}$ by Gödel’s theorem.

Comment: The first thing I thought of was the continuum hypothesis, but I'm not sure if it can be stated in SOA.

Comment: @none there is such a statement. $\aleph_1$ (or rather $\aleph_1+1$) is naturally a quotient of $2^\omega$ (or rather $2^{\omega\times\omega}$) under the definable relation of isomorphic wellorderings. So an injection from $2^\omega$ into $\aleph_1$ makes sense. However, we shouldn't hope for a definable injection of this kind but we may posit one by expanding the language using a new symbol.

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais No, there is no such statement. CH is a third-order $\Sigma^2_1$ statement that is not ZFC-provably equivalent to any $\Pi^2_1$ statement, and a fortiori to any second-order statement. If you expand the language with an extra symbol it is no longer the language of arithmetic.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, you are correct. I misused the word "statement" in its more general sense. Expanding the language is necessary as you explain. (Of course, any $\Sigma^2_1$ statement can be made second-order by adding a symbol for the witness.)

Comment: If you are talking about $\mathsf{Z}_2$, then my favorite example of an independent sentence is Borel determinacy. Although, there are plenty of other examples of independent sentences coming from descriptive set theory.

Comment: @FedorPakhomov Even $\Delta^0_4$ determinacy is beyond $\mathsf{Z}_2$.